# Read a file in Delphi program from a folder where the program is installed to by Inno Setup

Tags: delphi, installation, inno-setup

I would like to make an install program (using Inno Setup) for a desktop application I wrote using Delphi community edition. The code contains statements that open a text file on my C drive:

```
var
  filename: string;
begin
  filename := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Text_for_BC.txt';
  StringList1 := TStringList.Create;
  StringList1.LoadFromFile(fileName);
```

The program runs fine so long as the .exe and the text file live on my computer. However, were I to try and share the program with a friend by building an install program with Inno Setup, the above code would prevent a successful installation  since the path for the textfile (the path that Inno Setup asks me to supply) does not exist on a computer other than my own.

How should I have written the code above to  avoid the 'file not found' error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy both files to the same directory in Inno Setup.

And have your program load the file from its own directory:

```pascal
filename := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Text_for_BC.txt'
```